# Is it possible get two fields from parent model to one child model using foreign key?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, foreign-keys, relationship

consider the below models,

`class Country_City(models.Model):`

`country_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)`

`city_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)`

`class Register_user(models.Model):`

```
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='country', null=True)
city = models.ForeignKey(Country_City,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='city',null=True)
```

is it a right way to use?

I want to get two fields from parent model to child model

Comment: What is your exact requirement? why you need 2 fields as foreign key

Comment: do you have Country and Country_City two different models?

Comment: @rahul.m i have country name and city name in country_city model. I need to add these fields to register_user model. I want to create a register form with country & city fields. for that im storing in country and city details in country_city model  by fetching from api. Now you got my requirement clearly?

Answer (score 0):

That's simple you can access all fields from parent table to the child table and child to parent. Django gives you foreign key feature and reverse relationship as well.

```
class Country_City(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)



class Register_user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Country_City,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='city',null=True)
```

You can make models like this and if you want to access any fields from child to parent then you can use foreign key to access any fields from parent table  and reverse as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but If i try to access two fields from parent model it return only the field mentioned in the string representation only showing in child model. for example, if i'm returning 
def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name
then it shows country name in both child model 's fields. Can you please tell mw how to resolve this?